# How to translate django-allauth templates?

Tags: django, django-allauth

I've already translated my project in Malagasy (mg_Mg) but when installing django-allauth and override templates, translation won't be applied.

After `python manage.py makemessages`, `python manage.py compilemessages` and testing some translations eg: `sign up -> Hisoratra anarana` in render it show `sign up`.
But in my local app, all templates are translated correctly.

In config/setting.py

```py
import environ

BASE_DIR = environ.Path(__file__) - 2
...

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

LANGUAGES = [
    ('en-us', 'English'),
    ('fr-fr', 'French'),
    ('mg-mg', 'Malagasy'),
]

LOCALE_PATHS = [BASE_DIR('locale')]
```

In fandaharana/views.py

```py
def month(request, month_num, year_num):
    translation.activate('mg-mg')
    ...

    return render(request, 'month.html', data)
```